# divide 2 string values and return result as string

Tags: delphi

I want to  divide 2 string values and return the result as a string.
Input can be numbers like 1.234  or 1,234  both number formats.
Why does  the  function StrToFloatDef always return 0 ?
What is the best way to solve this  problem.

```
function divideStrings(Z, N: string): string;
var
  dZ, dN, dResult: Double;
  DecimalSeparator: Char;
begin
  DecimalSeparator := ','; // Set default decimal separator

  // Check if the input strings use dot as decimal separator
  if Pos('.', Z) > 0 then
  begin
    DecimalSeparator := '.';
    Z := StringReplace(Z, '.', DecimalSeparator, [rfReplaceAll]);
  end;
  if Pos('.', N) > 0 then
  begin
    DecimalSeparator := '.';
    N := StringReplace(N, '.', DecimalSeparator, [rfReplaceAll]);
  end;

  // Convert the strings to numbers
  dZ := StrToFloatDef(Z, 0, TFormatSettings.Create(DecimalSeparator));
  dN := StrToFloatDef(N, 0, TFormatSettings.Create(DecimalSeparator));

  // Divide the numbers
  if dN <> 0 then
    dResult := dZ / dN
  else
    dResult := 0; // or raise an exception, depending on your requirements

  // Convert the result back to a string
  Result := FloatToStr(dResult, TFormatSettings.Create(DecimalSeparator));
end;
```

Comment: You are replacing . (dot) by decimalSeparator who is equals to . (dot) too. Do not check the Pos and always do Z := Z.Replace('.', DecimalSeparator). You got 0 the default value because your string contains an invalid float number

Comment: Also, `TFormatSettings.Create` expects a locale name instead of the value for the DecimalSeparator.

Comment: Consider [accepting answers to your questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1362082/franz?tab=questions) again.

Comment: @AmigoJack: If only more users would consider that - maybe if we just stop helping people who don't bother to accept answers until they learn to do so it would help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're making it way too complicated:

```
function divideStrings(const Z, N: string): string;
  begin
    Result := FloatToStr(
                StrToFloat(Z.Replace('.',FormatSettings.DecimalSeparator).Replace(',',FormatSettings.DecimalSeparator))/
                StrToFloat(N.Replace('.',FormatSettings.DecimalSeparator).Replace(',',FormatSettings.DecimalSeparator))).Replace(FormatSettings.DecimalSeparator,',')
  end;
```

The two StrToFloat calls convert any decimal point ('.' or ',') into the one that the system uses before converting them to a floating point number, thus ensuring that the strings passed to StrToFloat always have the correct one.

The result from FloatToStr can then convert the system decimal point into whatever decimal point you want. As it is, in the code above, the result is always returned with ',' as decimal point, but if you replace the final ',' with '.' then it will always return '.' as decimal point, regardless of the system setting.

Also, you should use CONST on the string parameters since you are not modifying them in the function - this will allow the compiler to optimize the code (the .Replace does not modify the variable - it returns a new string with the replacement done, leaving the original string unmodified).